# Running my shell script instead of Ubuntu's built-in file

Tags: command-line, passwd

I have my shell script ready to be run.

But my problem is when I need user to run my shell script and not the Ubuntu's built-in file

For example, I want user to run my passwd shell script and not Ubuntu's passwd at /usr/bin/passwd

I have written alias on the .bashrc which look like this

```
alias passwd='./passwd'
```

My question is how do I make user to run my passwd instead of Ubuntu's passwd?
How do I disable the real passwd file?

Off-topic question, how do I override sudo?
Because my shell script contains sudo which will print out the required password at first run.

Comment: Overriding that type of utility is generally a really bad idea. Why don't you simply call your own version differently and put it in your `$PATH`?

Comment: I need too as the assignment requirement. It's about Computer Security where I need to make user think he/she is running the real command while truth is they're running my command.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the name for the alias, like `alias passwd='/home/Unknown/bin/passwd'`. This is often done by default for some commands like `ls` or `grep`, like `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`. [Some background in here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29).

To run the original command and not the alias, you might use `command passwd stuff-to-do`.

That being said, substituting security-related binaries is a dumb idea.

**EDIT:**
`.bashrc` is not read in non-interactive shell by default, that is when running a script, a shell used by the script does not read the `.bashrc` file. You might use a function for that in `.bashrc` and then `export` it, like:

```
passwd(){
    /home/Unknown/bin/passwd
}
export -f passwd
```

I did not test that with `passwd`, but it should work.

Some of the details come from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases)'s answers.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry for not double checking my question. My alias is perfect with the name as well and also the diretory. Just need to access my passwd instead of Ubuntu's passwd

Comment: Did  passwd(){ passwd } export -f passwd on my .bashrc but still the real passwd override my passwd file. Or did I wrote wrong? My file is at the root directory.

Comment: @Unknown test with `type passwd`. Also, do you do `source ~/.bashrc` or perhaps open a new terminal to check? If not, editing a file is not enough to make the alias work.

Answer (score 0):

As said in previous answers, best practice is to not name your script with the same name of an already existing system file/command.

If you really have to call it like that, then perhaps at least add the .sh to diversify a bit, e.g. call you script 'passwd.sh' (in general, also a best practice for shell scripts) so you minimize chances of confusion.

As for your question, I would suggest to create a bin directory under your home directory or perhaps (if you have rights) place it in /usr/local/bin and then amend the user PATH variable so that the scripts in the chosen location are found/accessible, for example:

```
$ cd; mkdir bin
$ export PATH="$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Note that the PATH variable may already contain those locations, best check beforehand via:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Comment: I have to name my file the same with passwd because my assignment is Computer Security related where I need to make user think he/she is running the real command while truth is they're running my command. My problem is overriding the real command with alias